# How to set TCP options in .NET Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, spoofing

I'm trying to mimic some traffic I sniffed from a device in my home with C#. The single TCP packet I'm trying to recreate right now (and also the first SYN packet that is sent from the device) has the following options according to Wireshark:

[image: TCP options: Maximum segment size, SACK permitted, Timestamps, No-operation (NOP), Window scale]
There does not appear to be a method of setting these options with .NET's Socket class (Listed TCP level options are BsdUrgent, Expedited and NoDelay). Is there any way I will still be able to accomplish setting these options at all or to custom values in .NET?

If there is no such option in .NET, is there any other way to do this manually? I tried using Nping, but again there doesn't seem to be an option to set tcp options either.